# Azure function output to queue AND return http response

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that is triggered by a http request and uses bindings to output to an Azure storage queue AND return a http response.

This works when coded for dotnet-isolated, making use of the Functions.Worker assemblies. First I declare a type for both the queue message and http response:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;

namespace SmsRouter.AzFunc
{
    public class QueueAndHttpOutputType
    {
        [QueueOutput("%SendSmsQueueName%")]
        public string QueueMessage { get; set; } = "";

        public HttpResponseData HttpResponse { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I use this as the return type for the Azure Function:

```
[Function(nameof(SendSimpleSms))]
        public async Task<QueueAndHttpOutputType> SendSimpleSms([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "v1.0/simple-sms")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
```

Unfortunately, I need to downgrade my solution to use dotnet 3.1 and the in-process model of Azure Functions due to [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/532).

Does anyone know how I can achieve the same behaviour using the old style in-process Azure Function?

Comment: I am trying to get the similar thing working with .Net 5 with a Http trigger having a Queue as output binding. Most of the examples I see for 3.1 or lower. Will apprecaite if you can check my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69910895/http-trigger-function-with-output-binding-to-queue

Comment: looks like you have an answer already :)

Comment: hving hard time finding namespace or nugget package 4 output binding  [QueueOutput("xx-data")]in MultiResponse. 
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Azure.Storage.Queues;
using Azure.Storage.Queues.Models;
namespace XXX.Models
{
    public class MultiResponse
    {
        [QueueOutput("xxx-data")] <= red squiggly under QueueOutput
        public string[] Messages { get; set; }
        public HttpResponseData HttpResponse { get; set; }
  }}
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69910895

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via injecting the `ServiceBus` output binding in the function itself.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendSimpleSms(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "v1.0/simple-sms")] HttpRequestData req,
        [Queue("%SendSmsQueueName%", Connection = "QueueConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<string> queue
            ExecutionContext executionContext)
```

To add the message in service bus invoke `AddAsync` method as shown below

```
await queue.AddAsync(message);
```

And return the http response via return statement; something like below

```
return new OkObjectResult(<<Your data here>>);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to publish to an Azure Storage Account Queue rather than Service Bus Queue.

Comment: In that case you can use `Queue` output binding as `[Queue("%SendSmsQueueName%", Connection = "QueueConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<CloudQueueMessage> queue
            ExecutionContext executionContext)`. You can also use `out T` also to write single message, for mulitple messages use `IAsyncCollector`. More information at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=csharp)

Comment: Thanks again but in my case the Azure Function needs to return a http response as well as publish a single message to a storage queue. I think your original answer put me on the right track, to return an IActionResult and use queue.AddAsync.

Comment: Yes, my last comment is related to change the `[ServiceBus` to `[Queue` binding.... Line #3 as per my answer. Now to add the message use, `await queue.AddAsync(message);`

Answer (score 0):

To write to the storage account queue, as opposed to a service bus queue in the accepted answer, I used the following:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(SendSimpleSms))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendSimpleSms([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "v1.0/simple-sms")] HttpRequest req,
            [Queue("%SendSmsQueueName%")] IAsyncCollector<string> queue)
        {
                await queue.AddAsync(jsonString);
                ...
                return new OkObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serviceRefResponse));
}
```