# Http trigger function with output binding to queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-http, azure-function-queue

I have a http triggered function in .Net5, isolated function.

I am having hard time getting the output binding working for this https function.

The https function retrieves a list of objects. These objects need to be added as separate messages to the queue.

```
[FunctionName("TestQueueOutput")]
[return: Queue("myqueue-items", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]    
public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,          
            FunctionContext context)
{
    HttpResponseData okResponse = null; 
    okResponse = req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);     

    // List of Objects
    var _list= await _repo.Get();
    await okResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(_list);
    return okResponse;       
}
```

When I run the function, http response can see the list but nothing in the queue defined in Azure.

I further followed the following article for adding output binding to Http trigger.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-storage-queue-vs?tabs=in-process

When I add the Multiresponse class for Isolated process, the output binding  for the QueueOutput, the function gives red squiggly lines for it. Can't find the correct nugget package to fix it.

[image: Output binding]

I spent countless hours to get the list items added to the queue as messages.

I am doing it right? Any guidance will be appreciated

**Update #1**: when I added the `MultiResponse` class, I can't figure out how to resolve the `QueueOutput` issue as in the following image:

[image: QueueOutput Binding in MultiResponse class]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to take a look at. For one, you expect to return `HttpResponseData`, but also have a `return` binding setup. And, as the `HttpResponseData` expects, you're returning a `HttpResponse`. But the `returns` binding is trying to translate that into a queue message. And the message information seems to be written to the response body, which is not how it should work.

As per the article you linked, try the following:

1. Add a class to your project, calling it `MultiRepsonse`
2. Implement the `MultiResponse` class something like below
3. Use the `MultiResponse` class in your Function like below

This implements the MultiResponse, tells the Function to use it and enables you to return a `HttpResonse` while writing messages to the queue. Beware: browser-written, non-validated code below.

##### MultiRespsonse.cs

```cs
public class MultiResponse
{
    [QueueOutput("myqueue-items",Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
    public string[] Messages { get; set; }

    public HttpResponseData HttpResponse { get; set; }
}
```

##### TestQueueOutput.cs

```cs
[FunctionName("TestQueueOutput")]
public async Task<MultiResponse> RunAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    FunctionContext context)
{
    var response = new MultiResponse();
    response.HttpResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    var _list = await _repo.Get();
    response.Messages = new string[_list.Count];
    foreach (var item in _list)
    {
        // Add the item to the list
    }

    return response;       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the return type to be changed to MultiResponse. I will try it. However I am still trying to figure out how to resolve the "QueueOutput" binding issue in the MultiResponse class. I have tried including the relevant namepsaces but there is something I am missing. Please see the new image added to my edited question at the bottom. Appreicate your timely reply.

Comment: The missing nugget package was Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage..just in case anyone will have issue.